# How to change the namespace of a variable in python?

Tags: python, namespaces

There is a type float32 in tensorflow/python/dypes.py.

After `import tensorflow as tf`,
when we I want to use the type, often we just need to type `tf.float32`, instead of `tf.python.dtypes.float32`.

It seems the namespace of float32 is changed into larger python module tensorflow.
How is this implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name space in python is all handled on the `__init__.py` file.

Say I have a package `foop` with files `foo.py` and `foo2.py` with some functions like `bar()` and `baz()` in `foo` and `bar2()` in `foo2`

if in the package level I define my `__init__.py` as follows:

```
import * from `foop.foo`
import * from `foop.foo2`
```

then when I need to use my package to call any of the methods I can just do.

```
import foo

foo.bar()
foo.bar2()
etc
```